Cloudwatch metrics, Terraform, Grafana alarms, Kubernetes
I need to setup CloudWatch metric alarms using Grafana, terraform, Kubernetes w/ helm, and I can't for the life of me find any resources that show how it should all work together.  I can find bits and pieces but nothing that works all together the way I need it to.  Sadly, I can't post anything from my code base for work reasons, but if anyone has a good resource where this exact thing has been done and I can see how they did it I would super appreciate it.  It just always seems like something breaks or doesn't like a change I've made.  I have this all setup working with teams in Grafana right now using the Grafana platform, but Teams isn't going to support webhooks anymore and we want it working through Terraform anyways.  Any guidance would be appreciated, and sorry for lack of being able to provide specific code.
I can get the metrics done in Terraform for AWS but once I want to add Grafana alarms directly everything just doesn't work.
I can get the metrics done in Terraform for AWS but once I want to add Grafana alarms directly everything just doesn't work.
It feels like this was never meant to be done this way if I'm being honest.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
